# How to add a url access date of a website in BiblaTex using Jabref reference Manager?

Tags: biblatex, urls, jabref

I want to add a url access date of the website I accessed to my bibliography but only at the end (after the url).

The MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage[style=numeric, 
natbib=true,
maxitems=1,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,
linktocpage=true,   

pdftitle={My Title},
pdfsubject={},
pdfauthor={My Name},
pdfkeywords={}]{hyperref}   


\bibliography{project}
\begin{document}
enter code here


@Online{ansys_2009,
Title                    = {Contact Technology Guide},
Author                   = {SAP IP Inc.},

   Url                      = {http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_ctec.pdf},
Year                     = {2009},
Month                    = {November},
Urldate                  = {Accessed on 25-04-2015},
Version                  = {12.1}}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]

I am using Jabref 2.10 reference manager to access my .bib file. I have already gone through similar questions asked in this forum but it doesn't seem to work for me. Also there is no `@online` in Jabref. So I type it as `@misc`.

Comment: Go to option/preferences and then `advanced`. activate `biblatex-mode` and everything will be fine.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am able to see the urldate field and note field now. When I enter accessed date in note field I get it before the url (as previous) and when I enter in the urldate field it still doesn't get published. I tried 'www', 'online' and 'misc' fields.

Comment: It might be that your biblatex-style simply doesn't use the urldate, though unlikely. Can you update the question above with your bibliography entry as well as the biblatex settings? A compilable example would be even better ;-)

Comment: by the way, added a picture: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse/blob/split/jabrefBiblatexMode.png

Comment: @Johannes_B I have described a MWE.

Comment: Answer added. Please have a look at the `blg`-file. There you get a warning message. Once you have seen this warning, you will be able to track down similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to tell JabRef about the use of `biblatex`. Go to options, preferences. In the advanced tab, select `BibLaTeX`-mode. You will now see all the fields available with `biblatex`, also types like `online`.

---

As far as the `biblatex`/`biber` combo is concerned, the stuff written into the `urldate` field is complete gibberish and hence is ignored. Everything in there should be *just* a date. Please have a look at the following output, depending on the language active, the entries look different.

[image: bruceBiblatexxUrldate]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Online{ansys_2009,
        Title                    = {Contact Technology Guide},
        Author                   = {SAP IP Inc.},

        Url                      = {http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu/Documentation12.1/121/ans_ctec.pdf},
        Year                     = {2009},
        Month                    = {November},
        Urldate                  = {2015-04-25},
        Version                  = {12.1}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,DIV=16,numbers=noenddot,english,french,ngerman]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric, 
    natbib=true,
    maxitems=1,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,
    linktocpage=true,   
    pdftitle={My Title},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfauthor={My Name},
pdfkeywords={}]{hyperref}   


%\bibliography{\jobname}% PLease note, that is deprecated
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\fullcite{ansys_2009}\par
\selectlanguage{french}
\fullcite{ansys_2009}\par
\selectlanguage{english}
\fullcite{ansys_2009}\par

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I changed fontsize and type area to get a nice screenshot, just ignore those changes ;-)